# Infinite rotation of an Image in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose

How to do my image to rotate infinitely?

This is my code but animation does not work

```kotlin
 val angle: Float by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = 360F,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                tween(2000))
        )
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.sonar_scanner),
            "image",
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .rotate(angle),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
        )
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [`InfiniteTransition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/InfiniteTransition) using [**`rememberInfiniteTransition`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#rememberInfiniteTransition()).
Something like

```
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val angle by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
    initialValue = 0F,
    targetValue = 360F,
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = tween(2000, easing = LinearEasing)
    )
)
```

Just a note.
Instead of using

```
Modifier.rotate(angle)
```

You can use

```
     Modifier
        .graphicsLayer {
            rotationZ = angle
        }
```

As you can check in the doc:

> Prefer this version when you have layer properties backed by a `androidx.compose.runtime.State` or an animated value as reading a state inside `block` will only cause the layer properties update without triggering recomposition and relayout.

Comment: Is there a way to pause and resume this animation without jumping?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pre-defined API for infinite animations for such use cases in my opinion.

```
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val angle by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
    initialValue = 0f,
    targetValue = 360f,
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = keyframes {
            durationMillis = 1000
        }
    )
)
```